# How to check which version docker image is built upon

Tags: docker

I have a docker image sitting in Artifactory.
How to check what is "base image version is"?

e.g.
My dockerimage in artifactory created based on docker file like this

```
FROM test-image:v1.0.0
...
```

Now after the build, how can i find that this image is built on `v1.0.0`

I tried doing `docker inspect <imagename>` it didn't help me to find the version of `test-image`.
Is there anyway I can find this version?

Comment: I would recommend also https://github.com/wagoodman/dive, a  tool for exploring a docker image, layer contents,

Answer (score 6):

You can use `docker image history` to see filesystem layers that the image consists of.

For example, assuming that you have image called `app`.

```
docker image history app
```

the result will look something like this.

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
7a85c25a7a6b        3 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node" "index.js"]      0B                  
339d3cb45826        3 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:15f5040b90b2035eb…   471B                
d7c2ba41aed4        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /node/app             0B                  
da8751259bd7        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 5000                  0B                  
25d4e098fa1b        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PORT=5000                0B                  
0e2e78467169        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node"]                 0B                  
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B                  
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:238737301d473041…   116B                
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex   && savedAptMark="$(apt-…   9.58MB              
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.4      0B                  
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print…   100MB               
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_VERSION=14.4.0      0B                  
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c groupadd --gid 1000 node   && use…   333kB               
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:57b431451a292755d…   55.3MB
```

Look at the IMAGE column and the entry that is right above the first `<missing>`, in this case - `0e2e78467169`. That is the ID of the image that the new image has been built from. Now you can list all images and find the corresponding one.

```
docker image ls | grep 0e2e78467169
```

Example output:

```
node                         14-stretch-slim     0e2e78467169        5 weeks ago         165MB
```

this (`node:14-stretch-slim`) is the image I used to build the new one from.

Comment: all I see there is "latest", how does that help

Answer (score 2):

A more compact version of @Matus answer can be

```
(image=my_image docker inspect $(docker image history $image | awk '{print $1}' | grep -i -B 1 '<missing>' | head -1) | jq ".[].RepoTags")
```

output

```
[
  "ubuntu:latest"
]
```

The above command base on the pattern of docker history, as I observed that history return base image before the first occurrence of `<missing>`

Comment: thanks I liked it, just FYI, in-case you wanted to see only "ubuntu:latest" as output just add `[]` at the end like this `jq ".[].RepoTags[]"`